# Why is 1.8 missing from RAD's Java project facet drop-down?

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal, ibm-rad

This is an issue with a runtime of type WebSphere Portal v8.5.

[image]

Note the runtime composition, which includes "Java Runtime Environment v1.7".

From HCL Portal's point of view,

```
C:\Portal85\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer_ND\bin>managesdk -listAvailable -verbose
WAS_HOME C:\Portal85\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer_ND
CWSDK1003I: Available SDKs :
CWSDK1005I: SDK name: 1.7_64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.version.1.7_64=1.7
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.bits.1.7_64=64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.location.1.7_64=${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/java_1.7_64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.platform.1.7_64=windows
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.architecture.1.7_64=x86_64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.nativeLibPath.1.7_64=${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/lib/native/win/x86_64/

CWSDK1005I: SDK name: 1.8_64_bundled
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.version.1.8_64_bundled=1.8
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.bits.1.8_64_bundled=64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.location.1.8_64_bundled=${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/java
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.platform.1.8_64_bundled=windows
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.architecture.1.8_64_bundled=x86_64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.nativeLibPath.1.8_64_bundled=${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/lib/native/win/x86_64/

CWSDK1001I: Successfully performed the requested managesdk task.

C:\Portal85\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer_ND\bin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check the feature pack (FP) updates to WebSphere 8.5. I believe one of the FP is required to get the Java 1.8.